# Converting audio and video to NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, file

I would like to confirm what the recommended ways are to convert audio and video files into NSData objects. Is + dataWithContentsOfFile: the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For videos since the only thing you have is the URL, yes dataWithContentsofFile is probably the best way to get the data for it.

Answer (score 4):

That's not a conversion, and it doesn't matter what's in the file—video, audio, text, game data, random garbage, or nothing at all. NSData just gives you the plain bytes; you'll need to pass either the data or the original pathname or URL to a higher-level class (such as UIImage, AVAudioPlayer, or MPMoviePlayerController) to actually show or play it.

In fact, MPMoviePlayerController does not even accept a data object—it *only* accepts URLs.

Comment: Huh? What was unhelpful about my answer?